# ASP.Net MVC3 ViewModel with Radio Button not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Here is my ViewModel class which i am binding with a radio button and check box

```
public class MyListViewModel
{
    public bool Isselected { get; set; }
    public Int32 ID { get; set; }      
    public string EmpName { get; set; }
    
}
```

**Issue:** ***For check box in a controller class i can able to see IsSelected property with the binded model is true if select. But in case of Radio button it always shows false. Any help appreciated***

**Check Box**

Razor code

```
 @Html.CheckBox(myListObj.Isselected.ToString(), myListObj.Isselected, 
  new { id = myListObj.Isselected.ToString() })
```

Produced HTML

```
 <input type="checkbox" value="true" name="myListObj[0].Isselected" id="22">
 <input type="hidden" value="false" name="myListObj[0].Isselected">
```

**Radio Button**

Razor:

```
 @Html.RadioButton(myListObj.Isselected.ToString(), myListObj.ID, 
 myListObj.Isselected, new { id = myListObj.Isselected.ToString() })
```

Html:

```
<input type="radio" value="6"
 name="myListObj[0].Isselected" id="myListObj[0].Isselected">
```

What could be the problem here?

```
Edited: 
What could be the code for binding a model with multiselect radio button. 
I mean user can select more than one Employee from a list. 
I want to know what are the employees selected with the help of Model Binding 
class with the property IsSelected. Please suggest me the possible way.
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using `Html.CheckBox` helper over `Html.CheckBoxFor` helper (same goes with radio)?

Comment: I try using CheckBoxFor and see

Comment: @BradChristie, i am using a collection IEnumarable<MyViewModel> is a model property for my view. I am looping through each and constructing. So in this case how can i use CheckBoxFor? Is it possible?

Comment: `@for (Int32 i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++) { @html.CheckBoxFor(x => Model[i].Isselected) }` would be one way (to retain indexes).

Comment: Please put the controller source code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `value` property of the radio button is what gets sent to the server, so in this case, the value `6` is being sent but the server can't stick `6` into `Isselected` b/c `Isselected` is of type `boolean`.

You need to change the html to this

```
@Html.RadioButton(myListObj.Isselected.ToString(), true, myListObj.Isselected, new { id = myListObj.Isselected.ToString() })
```

Note how I changed `myListObj.ID` to just `true`. This says to the browser "if the user selects this radio button, send the value `true` to the server".

Alternatively, you could change `Isselected` to a `double?` and continue using the `ID` value. This way, if the radio button is not selected, the server will see `null`; if it is selected, the server will see `6`.